# Database connection issue in groovy

Tags: groovy, database-connection

Unable to connect to database

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:databasename", "USERNAME","Password", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
```

Error: No suitable driver found.

I have a different test suite which has same database connection. If I run that test suite and run my present test suite my code works without any error

I am using ojdbc6.jar

Comment: how do you run this?  most likely the jar does not get picked up (assuming the uri there is correct for oracle)

Comment: @cfrick I am facing this problem when i'm running groovy script

Comment: is this your whole groovy script?  how would it know about the jar oracle jar then?

Comment: Valid point, I ran my test suite (it has 2 test cases). The first one failed because of db connection (assuming it dint pick the jar)and the second one was successful.

Comment: it's hard to help here, if you avoid anwering the question, how you run this.  so a shot in the dark: `groovy -cp ojdbc6.jar thescript.groovy`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put the `ojdbc6.jar` in the classpath of groovy when running.  E.g.

```
groovy -cp ojdbc6.jar thescript.groovy
```